# Pointfree version of a function using Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to make the following function pointfree. I am not sure how I can pass the arguement to the inner function though. I am using Ramda.js, but I think the concept is more general than that. Here is the code I have.

```
search = function(id) {
  return find(propEq('id', id), items)
}
```

Here, you will notice that the `id` parameter is passed to the inner function `propEq`. That's the part I am unsure of.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. Also, the code you posted is already point-free.

Comment: @azium, It is not point-free, `id` is the point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is more general than Ramda, but Ramda does have several functions to make things like this easier, especially [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge).

This can be written points-free with `useWith` like this:

```
var search = useWith(find, propEq('id'), identity);
search(2, items); //=> {id:  2}
```

You can see it in action [on the Ramda REPL](http://bit.ly/1SNd49M).

Comment: Looking back at this years later, I realize that so long as you're ok with calling it as `search (2) (items)`, then this is much better written as `const search = compose (find, propEq ('id'))`.  (You can see this on the [Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20search%20%3D%20compose%20%28find%2C%20propEq%20%28%27id%27%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20items%20%3D%20%5B%7Bid%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7Bid%3A%202%7D%2C%20%7Bid%3A%203%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Asearch%20%282%29%20%28items%29))

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of tinkering you can get a point-free version, but the auto-currying gave issues, so I had to duplicate some functionality by currying the functions manually. This is the one liner:

```
search = compose(flip(find)(items), propEq('id'))
```

Using ES6 syntax for brevity:

```
var {compose} = R

var find = f => xs => R.find(f, xs)
var propEq = p => x => R.propEq(p, x)
var flip = f => a => b => f(b)(a)

// Example:

var items = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]

// point-full
var search = function(id) {
  return find(propEq('id')(id))(items)
}

console.log(search(2))

// point-free
search = compose(flip(find)(items), propEq('id'))

console.log(search(2))
```

It is point-less though.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/batedi/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

You just have to curry it first. Then you can give it the id first, and items will be the output of the function that precedes it.

Ex:

```
const search = R.curry((id, items) => R.find(R.propEq('id', id), items));

const testSearch = R.pipe(
  R.identity(() => [{id: '123'}, {id: 'asdf'}]),
  search('123')
);

testSearch(); // { id: '123' }
```